# Very Slow Maven

Tags: performance, maven

```
C:\eclipse\workspace>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.5.2 
Maven home: C:\apache\maven\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
```

---

```
C:\eclipse\workspace>mvn archetype:generate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
Progress (1): 6.4 kB
```

Maven is very slow on my computer. I executed `mvn archetype:generate` and it's sitting at this point for 15 minutes. My internet connection is fast. I can download a large library from the internet in short time.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: You may  have a networking problem.  Is the latest Java 8 an option?

Comment: Run mvn with `-X` option to see debug info. Get a thread dump via `jstack` and see where it's hung.

Comment: this is how thread dump looks like

Comment: tid=0x000000000cc57000 is waiting on                                                      - locked <0x00000007d8512088> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)                                                      
2018-01-06 09:32:07
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode):
....
"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x000000000cc60000 nid=0x7fc in Object.wait() [0x000000000e00f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitorjava.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
        - locked <0x00000007d8512088> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

Comment: I tried java 8, same behavior. > mvn archetype:generate command get stuck.

Comment: I am still struggling with this issue. On the same desktop I have NetBeans IDE and same example Spring Boot project. NetBeans can load all the dependencies in POM but Eclipse get stuck. I have tried Neon and Oxygen but to no avail. It looks like there is some kind of setting in Eclipse which I don't know how to set for Eclipse to download all the dependencies. Anyone knows? Thanks

Comment: Same problem with Maven 3.5.3.
Build time with
`3.5.0`: `3 minutes` and with:
`3.5.3`: `7m30s`.

Comment: 2022, good connection and it still takes a very long time to load. Why is it trying to "download the world"? Very bad idea IMHO. Use convention over configuration, not "all options of the world". Maven is getting obsolete for that, it seems like a design bug.

Answer (score 0):

Since maven does not work well at slow internet connection, local proxy and cache maybe good idea.

[Repocache](https://github.com/pedia/repocache) is remarkable.

Add repocache.cfg

```
[mvn.upstream.apache]
url = https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
This will cache package at mvn/releases.
```

Change $HOME/.m2/settings.xml add:

```xml
<repository>
  <id>apache</id>
  <url>http://127.0.0.1:5000/mvn/apache</url>
</repository>
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be a lost network disk connection. I had a similar issue. And after dropping the not available network disk, it started to work normally. More about this [Slow maven unit tests](https://zero-to-hero-dev.com/others/32-slow-java-unit-tests)